# Setting the position for Android Gridview items

Tags: android, gridview, gravity

My Gridview can display 21 (3x7) images at a time. No problem with that.. Able to display 21 images.

21 images display:- (No issue)

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7

8   9   10  11  12  13  14

15  16  17  18  19  29  21
```

But, if I want to display only 10 images then the problem is coming. Images are starting displaying after 1.5 rows. But, I want to start the images display from the first row it self for any number of images ( 1 - 21)

=============

..Empty Line is coming on the top..

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7

8   9   10
```

Please help me on this... how to arrange the images properly from starting row..

I have tried this for all the values:

**gridview [ iIndex ].setGravity( Gravity.START );**

Comment: Can you please, provide some code..

Comment: There is probably a bug in your GridviewAdapter, ie when your overloaded getItemId is getting called it is returning empty items or null items.